# напугал кота сосиской - Is it an idiom?

Tags: idioms

"напугал кота сосиской" seems to be an idiom. Is it? What does it mean?

Comment: English language analog is «Scare me with a good time», but it's not as poetic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It's an idiom. It means "to scare a cat with a sausage" - a ridiculous threat.

Comment: Ahhh, Google only gave me "frightened cat sausage" ;-)

Comment: Actually it means "scared a cat with a Vienna sausage" (not "to scare", and sausage is колбаса)

Answer (score 17):

There are some variations of this, like:

`Напугал кота сметаной`

or

`Напугал кота котлетой!`

Means `"trying to scare a cat with a piece of steak"`

Also some other animals are involved to in the similar pattern and meaning:

`Напугал кобеля буханкой`

Above animals do like a food mentioned, but a hedgehog just doesn't care, isn't afraid of:

`Напугал ежа голой жопой`

Means `"[you are] scaring a hedgehog with a bare ass"`

other:
`напугал козла капустой`

or

`напугал козла огородом`

and

`напугал барана новыми воротами`

The same attitude can be expressed by a bit different but close analogue:

`не так страшен черт, как его малюют`

Comment: +1 for scaring a hedgehog

Answer (score 2):

In addition to many examples that Ruslan Gerasimov has made there is

```
Только не бросай меня в терновый куст.
```

A phrase which comes from a folk tale, where a rabbit begs a wolf who has captured him, to do whatever the wolf desires except throwing the said rabbit into a thorn bush. Once the wolf throws him there, the rabbit quickly runs away.

Unlike the other variants, which signify the futility of the action, this one actually baits it.

Comment: That's an idiom coming from the English language - the original source is Cherokee and African American 19th century story Bre'r Rabbit and the Briar Patch; published wider and around the world in 20th century.